# No se como explicar el comportamiento de Spring Boot + Artemis

Tags: java, spring, activemq

estoy creando una aplicación simple de chat para aprender sobre el funcionamiento de Spring + Artemis Broker externo. Empece siguiendo el ejemplo del enlace [http://masterspringboot.com/messaging/artemismq/jms-messaging-with-spring-boot-and-remote-artemis-mq][1]. El cual funciona sin problemas, sin embargo utiliza el protocolo http que no me parece adecuado para una aplicación de chat que debe funcionar en tiempo real.
Así que quise utilizar websockets y STOMP por lo que añadí la clase de configuración:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/chat").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app").enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queues");
}

}
```

El primer error fue este:

```
Failed to start bean 'stompBrokerRelayMessageHandler'; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/reactivestreams/Publisher
```

Tras investigar un poco encontré en la doc de spring que para la comunicación entre spring y el broker se usa netty( el cual gestiona los hilos para que no queden bloqueados, pudiendo ser reutilizados durante nuevas peticiones ). Y haciendo caso a la doc de Spring añadí las dependencias:

```
implementation 'io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty'
implementation 'io.netty:netty-all'
```

Lo que me lleva al siguiente error:

```
[ient-loop-nio-1] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection failure in session _system_: Failed to connect: Conexión rehusada: /127.0.0.1:61613
```

A pesar de que en application.properties esta definido:

```
spring.artemis.port=61616
```

Mi siguiente paso es también indicar el puerto en el fichero de configuración:

```
registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app").enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queues").setRelayPort(61616);
```

Y vuelve a salir un error:

```
StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Received ERROR {message=[Security Error occurred: User name [guest] or password is invalid], content-type=[text/plain], content-length=[65]} session=_system_ text/plain payload=Security Error occurred: User name [guest] or password is invalid
```

Así que tambien indico user y password en el fichero de conf:

```
registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app").enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queues").setRelayPort(61616).setSystemLogin("developer").setSystemPasscode("password");
```

Según mi entendimiento he duplicado los valores de puerto, usuario y passcode en el fichero de conf y en application.properties, asi que elimino los valores de application.properties. Pero aparece el siguiente error:

```
DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination '/topic/messages' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from /127.0.0.1:39964. Username: null; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable
```

Asi que finalmente dejo los valores en el fichero de conf y en application.properties y todo queda OK sin errores.

Lo que me lleva a preguntarme el funcionamiento de Spring y Artemis y me gustaría confirmación ya que por mi mismo solo puedo especular.

Mis dudas serían:

- Creo que por un lado la configuracion del fichero de configuracion sirve para configurar la comunicación entre cliente(Spring) y servidor(Artemis), que supongo es la API JMS. Pero entonces ¿que configuran las opciones del fichero application.properties?
- La doc de Artemis dice que los acceptors son los que indican al servidor que tipo de conexiones clientes se permitiran. El Acceptor que configuro en Artemis sirve solo para las conexiones de clientes (digamos clientes web, moviles, etc..) que se conectan directamente al servidor Artemis o ¿es usado tambien para la comunicación entre spring - artemis, ya que spring esta actuando como cliente y artemis hace de servidor?.